# Filter and Email Excel File (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of accounts and relevant information that I have to split up and send specific accounts to certain people.  This has to be done about 50 times.  I already have a program setup that will filter, copy the data to a new file, and save.  Is there a way to set it up to then email this file based on a list of contacts?

Each account is covered by a region, so I have a list which has the region and the contact's email.  In the macro that splits by the regions, it has an array of these regions so is some kind of lookup possible from the list of contacts?

Code:

```
Sub SplitFile()

Dim rTemp As Range
Dim regions() As String

Set rTemp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combined").Range("AH2:AH1455")
regions = UniqueItems(rTemp, False)
For N = 1 To UBound(regions)
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DVal").Copy _
       after:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combined")
        .AutoFilterMode = False
'        .AutoFilter
        .Range("A1:BP1455").AutoFilter Field:=34, Criteria1:=regions(N)
              Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Range("A1:BP1455").Copy wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
              Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        For c = 1 To 68
            wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:BP2694").Columns(c).ColumnWidth = .Columns(c).ColumnWidth
        Next c
    End With

    With wb
        .Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
        .SaveAs Filename:="H:\" & regions(N) & " 14-12-11"
        .Close True
    End With

    Set wb = Nothing
Next N

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you want to do it programmaticaly using VB, you can do something like

```
 Dim msg As System.Web.Mail.MailMessage = New System.Web.Mail.MailMessage() 
 msg.From = "noone@nobody.com" 
 msg.To = "someone@somewhere.com" 
 msg.Subject = "Email with Attachment Demo" 
 msg.Body = "This is the main body of the email" 
 Dim attch As MailAttachment = New MailAttachment("C:\attachment.xls") 
 msg.Attachments.Add(attch) 
 SmtpMail.Send(msg)
```

Comment: Awesome, do you know how I can lookup the To contact from a list based on what region it is?

Comment: Can you post how your contacts and region list look like?

Comment: Also your dynamic allocation for the two variables give me errors, I'm using 2007, is that why?  Contact list is simply one column for region and one adjacent column with a corresponding contact.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble with the above, my mail macro is different; this is used with excel 2007:

```
Sub Mail()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "To Whom It May Concern:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "This is a test!" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 2" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 3" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 4"

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = "anyone@anywhere.com"
        .cc = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is only a test"
        .Body = strbody
        'You can add an attachment like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Jon

I am assuming the following.

1) Regions are in Col AH

2) Contacts are in Col AI

3) UniqueItems() in your code removes duplicates?

Please try the below code. I have commented the code so please go through them and make relevant changes. Especially to the part where you save the File. I have used Late Binding with Outlook.

***NOTE:*** I always test my code before posting but in the current scenario I cannot so do let me know if you find any errors.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SplitFile()
    '~~> Excel variables
    Dim wb As Workbook, wbtemp As Workbook
    Dim rTemp As Range, rng As Range
    Dim regions() As String, FileExt As String, flName As String
    Dim N As Long, FileFrmt As Long

    '~~> OutLook Variables
    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String, strTo As String

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    '~~> Just Regions
    Set rTemp = wb.Sheets("Combined").Range("AH2:AH1455")
    '~~> Regions and Email address. We wil require this later
    '~~> Tofind email addresses
    Set rng = wb.Sheets("Combined").Range("AH2:AI1455")

    regions = UniqueItems(rTemp, False)

    '~~> Create an instance of outlook
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For N = 1 To UBound(regions)
        Set wb1 = Workbooks.Add

        wb.Sheets("DVal").Copy after:=wb1.Sheets(1)

        With wb.Sheets("Combined")
            .AutoFilterMode = False
            With .Range("A1:BP1455")
                .AutoFilter Field:=34, Criteria1:=regions(N)
                '~~> I think you want to copy the filtered data???
                .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

                For c = 1 To 68
                    wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:BP2694").Columns(c).ColumnWidth = _
                    wb.Columns(c).ColumnWidth
                Next c
            End With
        End With

        '~~> Set the relevant Fileformat for Save As
        ' 51 = xlOpenXMLWorkbook (without macro's in 2007-2010, xlsx)
        ' 52 = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled (with or without macro's in 2007-2010, xlsm)
        ' 50 = xlExcel12 (Excel Binary Workbook in 2007-2010 with or without macro's, xlsb)
        ' 56 = xlExcel8 (97-2003 format in Excel 2007-2010, xls)

        FileFrmt = 52

        Select Case FileFrmt
        Case 50: FileExt = ".xlsb"
        Case 51: FileExt = ".xlsx"
        Case 52: FileExt = ".xlsm"
        Case 56: FileExt = ".xls"
        End Select

        '~~> Contruct the file name.
        flName = "H:\" & regions(N) & " 14-12-11" & FileExt

        '~~> Do the save as
        wb1.SaveAs Filename:=flName, FileFormat:=FileFrmt
        wb1.Close SaveChanges:=False

        '~~> Find the email address
        strTo = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(regions(N), rng, 2, 0)

        '~~> Create new email item
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        '~~> Create the body of the email here. Change as applicable
        strbody = "Dear Mr xyz..."

        With OutMail
            .To = strTo
            .Subject = regions(N) & " 14-12-11" '<~~ Change subject here
            .Body = strbody
            .Attachments.Add flName
            '~~> Uncomment the below if you just want to display the email
            '~~> and comment .Send
            '.Display
            .Send
        End With
    Next N

LetContinue:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    '~~> CleanUp
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set wb1 = Nothing
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    OutApp.Quit
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetContinue
End Sub
```